# Get IP in WCF RIA Services

Tags: .net, ip-address, wcf-ria-services, ria

Does anybody know how can I get IP address of client with RIA services. In WCF we have `OperationContext` for that. But it doesn't work with RIA services.

Comment: no aswers, i guess there is now any way to do it...

Answer (score 3):

You can use HttpContext.Current and APIs off of that today...

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `Invoke Operation` in your `DomainService` to get the IP adress like this:

```
[Invoke]
public string GetIPAddress()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName;
}
```

In the client you should write:

```
YourContext context = new YourContext();

InvokeOperation invokeOperation = context.GetIPAddress();

invokeOperation.Completed += (s, args) =>
{
    if (invokeOperation.HasError)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
        invokeOperation.MarkErrorAsHandled();
    }
    else
    {
        string ip = invokeOperation.Value.ToString();
    }
};
```